# Process monitoring

Tags: monitoring, memory-management

Is there an application that is capable of monitoring AND logging information (to file) about another process (in particular IIS aspnet_wp.exe) like (in periods of time):
- memory usage of process
- cpu usage

Or maybe there is another way to monitor IIS process?

Thanks Pawel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Microsoft.

> Process Monitor is an advanced
>   monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and
>   process/thread activity. It combines
>   the features of two legacy
>   Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and
>   Regmon, and adds an extensive list of
>   enhancements including rich and
>   non-destructive filtering,
>   comprehensive event properties such
>   session IDs and user names, reliable
>   process information, full thread
>   stacks with integrated symbol support
>   for each operation, simultaneous
>   **logging to a file**, and much more.

Answer (score 0):

One choice would be Process explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Does it allow to log info to file periodically, I don't see it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the ANTS Performance and Memory Profilers from [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/).  I'm using their memory profiler to track down some memory issues as I write this.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any monitoring system or framework that allows custom checks is capable of this.
You write your check and just put an extra line in it to post/print/put something to a file of your choice.

I for example use sensu for which I wright custom checks in ruby.

So I can easily do something like

```
if %x[{ping]}
  ok
  %x[{ print ‘all is well’ > syslog]}
end
```

and similar to that you can do for most other monitoring systems like Nagios etc.